# How do I "execute" another windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms.  I have a button on the first form that I want to bring up a form called form2.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 5):

```
public void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
     var form = new Form2();
     form.Show();
}
```

Comment: Or `ShowDialog()`, if you want to open it as modal window.

Comment: @kol - Yes. I wasn't sure which one to show. He probably wants ShowDialog

Comment: @Brandon - Yes, there are many things missing from this example. You need to add the OnClick method to the form class. You need to make sure that OnClick is wired to the button. You also need to ensure that you are using the correct form name instead of Form2

Comment: The type of namespace name "Form2" could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Brandon, you need to add the namespace of the class for your second form so it's available to the first form. (Also, for future reference, the first thing you should type after the words "get an error" or "get an exception" is the **exact** error or exception message you receive. The words "error" and "exception" are meaningless without the other information to go with them.)

Comment: How would you add the namespace?  I am a bit confused by this.

Answer (score 2):

```
YourOtherFormClass form2 = new YourOtherFormClass();
form2.Show();
```

This can be put in your button's on_click event handler, where `YourOtherFormClass` is the class of your second form.  You just need to instantiate it and then call the `Show()` method.

Comment: I am getting an error of "The type or namespace name "Form2" could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Is your Form2 class in a different namespace than your current class? If so use the `using` statement for Form2's namespace.

Comment: No, they are both in the same namespace.

Comment: Well, the namespaces have the same name, but not physically in the same namespace. would that make any difference?

Answer (score 1):

Double click on the button to create it's on-click handler, and simply do

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(); // or whatever the name of the class is
f2.Show();
```

Comment: I am getting an error of "The type or namespace name "Form2" could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"